# Calendar which move apart

Tags: android, caldroid

I would like to implement a mechanism/animation that makes when you press a cell in calendar, top and bottom (of calendar) move apart.

It's any example module or api for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider looking into the new Material Transitions in Android 5 and above.  The library includes an explode animation for all the elements that are not focused and animates them in any desired direction, while your desired cell is scaled to the entire screen in a new activity (called an Activity Transition).  Google's GitHub also provides libraries for compatibility with previous version of android.

This is how I would implement it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhiPJByIMrM